# Is there a projector alternative for unity that supports URP?

Tags: unity-game-engine

Question above.

I'm trying to make a projection that looks like a real 3d object from specific angles, similar to Superliminal, but I can't find a method that works with URP.

While unity has projectors, they don't support the pipeline, and URP's Decal system doesn't support perspective projection, only orthographic. Is there some tool or method I don't know about?

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://github.com/nyahoon-games/ProjectorForLWRP) repository may be helpful to you. It's quite outdated, however, I don't know which version of URP or Unity you're using, or what settings are you using (Forward or Deferred).

It is a renderer feature that can be easily added to your Scriptable Render Pipeline. To quote the original creator description:

> ...add a ProjectorRendererFeature to your ForwardRendererData. The user interface might look different in newer versions but there must be a similer interface.

How to use:

> Add a Projector For LWRP component to your Projector object, if you already have one. If you want to create a new Projector object, just add a Projector For LWRP component to an empty GameObject, then Projector component will also be added.

It's pretty straightforward. [Here's an official online document](https://nyahoon.com/products/projector-for-lwrp)

You still need to have the legacy projector component script in your project. Depending on your Unity version, you may (or may not) have it in your project.

Comment: Your answer could be improved by providing an example of the solution and how it helps the OP.

Comment: You're right. Thanks for pointing it out.